# CSS content counters breaks CSS in IE

Tags: css, html, browser, cross-browser

I do expect the site to require a few tweaks to work in IE although this time it appears like something is completely breaking the CSS in IE8 compatibility mode.

To start at the top with the logo position, I have added a red background to check its location and this is not even displayed, although you can see this in firefox. How come this is not being read correctly?

[Website](http://projects.web2works.co.uk/supremebeing/)

EDIT:

I have narrowed this down to the exact code which causes IE to break:

```
.content ol li:before {
content: counters(item, ".") ": "; 
counter-increment: item
}
```

How could I get around this? Without manually adding the numbers. I wanted the numbered list to work like: 1.1.2 etc

Comment: Link to the page in question?

Comment: looks the same on ie8 as firefox for me. it doesn't work in ie8 compatibility mode, but neither does the rest of the site, so i am guessing that doesn't bother you.

Comment: Narrow it down to a small and simple problem and than post the code in question here.

Comment: Yes this does bother me, I want this to work in at least IE7.

Comment: I have used HTML5 tags but not directly from CSS always wrapped in div's etc

Comment: Huh, so it turns out to be CSS counters. Well, they don't work in IE7 at all, and I'm not sure if there's a script-based solution out there for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generated content isn't supported in IE<8 ([see When can I use...](http://caniuse.com/#search=before)). A brief search didn't return any obvious alternative (a shim etc). Can you just accept that IE6/7 won't see your counters, or perhaps use [Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/)?

Comment: I have to say this isn't a very good solution (but there may not be) because the CSS parser in IE7 throws some kind of an error, therefor bypassing all the following styles in the CSS document! I'm having problems figuring out whether I can even leave this in the CSS

Comment: That definitely shouldn't be the case (generated content is in use everywhere, take a look at the source of this page). There is likely a bigger problem with your stylesheet.

Comment: This link verifies what I was saying... :)  I've had to move the rules to the bottom of my stylesheet so it doesn't break any following CSS, I guess you could put it in another stylesheet usign IE conditionals http://forrst.com/posts/Be_careful_of_list_counters_CSS_in_Internet_Ex-7pN

Comment: Ah I see, it's an issue with the counter rather than all generated content. That's useful to know, thanks. I guess the most elegant solution would be that used in the HTML5 Boilerplate, adding classes to the HTML tag based on IE version and targeting those. Then you can keep the related CSS together in your stylesheet.

Comment: Yeah I like the way boilerplate does it, actually using it in this project however want to keep all my rules in 1 file to reduce requests.. so still have to shift this code to the end of the file :(

Comment: There are methods that will resolve the parser error (counters still don't work, but the rest of your stylesheet does), see the other answers

Answer (score 3):

Having worked through this issue myself, to avoid the IE7 parser error, change:

```
content: counters(item, ".") ": ";
```

to

```
content: counters(item , ".") ": ";
```

Note the whitespace between item and the comma. You can also wrap item in parentheses and it seems to work with all major browsers, though it seems a bit nonstandard.

Comment: Given the revised question, this is the correct answer for IE7. Thank you!

Comment: I've written up a quick blog post about this with a demo page: http://jes.st/2013/ie7s-css-breaking-content-counter-bug

Answer (score 2):

[Transparent PNG images don't work in IE.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294714)

Here's a nice explanation and solution: http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6

Comment: "IE8 and less" So IE6 isn't the only browser with this issue.

Comment: Thanks, although I do not need transparent PNGs for this and wouldn't solve the CSS problems, more like cause more

Comment: Transparent PNGs work fine in IE7+. You only need to use something like supersleight for IE6 (and even then only if you deem it worth the extra effort).

Comment: @BoltClock - True, but that article was written before IE8 even existed. Pretty sure it still applies to IE7, and probably to IE8 too.