# CSS counters fail in IE9 but get fixed with IE devtools?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, ie-developer-tools

I have `<ol>`s utilizing css counters, working fine in Chrome:
4)
5)
6)...etc.

But in IE9, I get:
0)
0)
0)...just 0)'s.

If I launch IE's devtools and change the browser mode/document mode to something less than IE9/IE9 Standards, then revert back to IE9/IE9 Standards, the css counters appear correctly.  This is a fairly reliable fix, but I can't deploy telling users to do this.

Any ideas on ensuring that css counters work in IE9?

Thanks!
- Michael M.

```
ol.start-f-paren {list-style-type:none;counter-reset:sfp 5;}
ol.start-f-paren > li {counter-increment:sfp;}
ol.start-f-paren > li:before {content:counter(sfp, lower-alpha) ") ";}
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML> html5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is to make sure that when you have a counter rule in your css class, don't use spaces around commas, like so:
    counter(myCounter,upper-alpha);

as opposed to what I was doing:
    //breaks in IE
    counter(myCounter, upper-alpha);

When I apply the fix, IE9 seems more reliable viewing in IE9 standards mode. The jury is out if this is 100% reliable, but it's currently working.  It's explained well here: http://jes.st/2013/ie7s-css-breaking-content-counter-bug/

Comment: Now that's just bizarre.

Comment: Bizarre, and still not 100% reliable for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have `console.log()` somewhere in your JavaScript.

Problem is `IE9` when dev tools are closed doesn't have a console object, so it fails JavaScript execution. This problem is fixed in `IE10+`

use this instead of regular `console.log()`

```
var log = function(msg){
    if(typeof(console) !== "undefined"){
        console.log(msg);
    }
}
```

Let me know if it works, I had similar problem.

Comment: I commented out the console.logs, but it didn't help.  I'm not clear on how that would affect the CSS counters.

Sporadically, the css counters work in IE9, but mostly they don't, and there doesn't seem to be a reproducible pattern.

Comment: There's a response to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14983995/1913564 that seems to have "increased the probability" that the css renders correctly.  I can't say it's a solution, because it doesn't seem 100% reliable.